# Adding a custom button to Dropzone

Tags: dropzone.js

I have been googling this and trying to find a solution which seems to be pretty much impossible, I have dropzone integrated in to my application with the remove button, I want to add an additional button to each thumb nail is this possible to do? so two buttons per each thumbnail?

Answer (score 4):

**I have added custom download button for each file check below code**

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#form", { 
    maxFilesize: 2, // MB
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    dictRemoveFileConfirmation : 'Sure Want To Delete',
    init: function() {
         this.on("success", function(file, responseText) {
                 var filename = file.name;
                 $('#form').append("<input type='hidden' data='"+filename+"' name='files[]' value='"+responseText+"'>");
          });
         this.on("complete",function(file){
                 var newNode = document.createElement('a');
                 newNode.className = 'btn btn-primary btn-xs downloadbtn';
                 newNode.href = "<?= SITE_URL.''.'upload/attachments/' ?>"+file.name;
                 newNode.target = "_blank";
                 newNode.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download';
                 file.previewTemplate.appendChild(newNode);

            });
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you creating a custom theme for the thumbnail?  That is the easiest way to add buttons etc. http://www.dropzonejs.com/#theming

for example:

```
<div id="preview-template" style="display:none">
<div class="documents_drop_file_thumb">
    <div class="documents_drop_file_thumb_remove"><a class="dz-remove" href="javascript:undefined;" data-dz-remove=""><img src="<?php echo DIRECTORY_INDEX . "/"; ?>images/remove_file.png" alt=""></a></div>
    <div class="documents_drop_file_thumb_EXTRABUTTON"><a class="dz-extraaction" href="javascript:undefined;"><img src="<?php echo DIRECTORY_INDEX . "/"; ?>images/extrabutton_file.png" alt=""></a></div>
    <div class="documents_drop_file_thumb_image"><img data-dz-thumbnail /></div>
    <div class="documents_drop_file_thumb_progress_status"><span data-dz-name></span></div>
    <div class="documents_drop_file_thumb_progress"><span class="dz-upload" data-dz-uploadprogress></div>
    <div class="documents_drop_file_thumb_progress_status"><span data-dz-errormessage></span></div>
</div>
```

Then all you need is a dropzone parameter when setting up your dz.

```
    //Prepare the drop zone area
var myNewdDropzone = new Dropzone("#idOfForm",  {
    url: "my-ajax.php",
    method: "POST",
    addRemoveLinks: false,
    clickable: true,
    previewTemplate: document.querySelector('#preview-template').innerHTML,
    init : function() {
        this.on("addedfile", function(file) { new_file_added(file); });
        this.on("thumbnail", function(file,fileurl) { new_thumbnail_added(file); });
        this.on("removedfile", function(file) { new_file_removed(file); });
        this.on("totaluploadprogress", function(progress) { display_progress(progress); });
        this.on("queuecomplete", function() { all_files_uploaded(); });
        //this.on("processing", function(file) { new_file_processed(file); });
    }
});
```

Pay particular attention to:

EXTRABUTTON - that is your shiny new button area

addRemoveLinks - your template has them, so don't add new ones (with a nice icon, assuming you have a nice icon with that name)

previewTemplate - that sets up your new thumbnail template

this.on("etcetcetc") calls functions driven by events if you need them

Comment: OH yes, your template should be display:none unless you want it to appear somewhere on the page :)